# Thread Pool with Spring @Value for Pool size doesnt run properly

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I have a thread pooling and the input for the pool size is passed using the @value in spring whose reference is in the .properties file. as shown below:

```
@Value("${project.threadPoolSize}")
private static int threadPoolSize;

private static ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

@PostConstruct
public void MasterProcessService() {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("Entering processServices in MasterProcessThread ");
```

When I try to give the thread pool size using the annotation value, it just pool inly 1 thread and perform sleep operation but doesnt pool other threads later on.

When I pass the thread pool size directly using :

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(11);
```

It pools all the threads and perfrom sleep and run states as defined.

Can any one help me using the @Value in the thread pool size instead of directly defining a number ?

Comment: `@Value` doesn't work on `static` fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all due to 2 facts:

1 - `@Value` doesn't work on static fields. If you want to populate it with the value - don't make it static.

```
@Value("${project.threadPoolSize}")
private static int threadPoolSize;
```

2 - static `threadPool` variable is created first, before the `threadPoolSize` is populated with the value (if it's not a static yet).

If you need to set a value to some static field via `@Value`, you can try to do it as follows:

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService threadPool;

@Value("${project.threadPoolSize}")
public void setThreadPool(Integer poolSize) {
    threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
}
```

Value injection will be called on start up and will call the `setThreadPool` method which will init you static variable with defined pool size.

Comment: Can I use my threadPool size to be dynamic. if yes how to aceive it ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn’t allow to inject value into static variables. Use `java.lang.Integer` instead.